# Android: SOAP webservice call giving nullpointerexception

Tags: android, soap, nullpointerexception

Hi my webservice when tested using the SoapUI is giving perfect output ,But when i am trying to access from the code it is giving nullpointer exception, not sure what am i doing wrong
below is my code and working URL.

```
public class Insertdata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {  

        private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
        private final String URL = "http://10.188.7.102/GetCarpoolDetails/GetCarpoolDetailsService.svc?wsdl";
        private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IGetCarpoolDetailsService/getUserDetails";
        private final String METHOD_NAME = "getUserDetails";
        HttpResponse response = null;
        String result = null;
        String status;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        SoapObject soapObject;
        soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        soapObject.addProperty("Empid","44");

   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

        System.out.println("envelope---------"+envelope.bodyOut);

         HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport;
        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try{
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            status = response.toString();

            System.out.println("status==========="+status);

            System.out.println("Posted Ride Sucsessfully");

       }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("checking error====="+e.toString());
       }
        return null;

   }

 }
```

Below is my stackTrace

```
02-17 09:31:32.863: I/System.out(5219): envelope---------getUserDetails{Empid=44; }
02-17 09:31:32.883: D/dalvikvm(5219): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 297K, 14% free 2694K/3132K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
02-17 09:31:33.113: I/System.out(5219): checking error=====java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any help is really really appreciated.

Comment: I think namespace should be "http://tempuri.org/"

Comment: please post your full logcat

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi hi here is my log cat http://pastebin.com/F7pyeM7b  iam not getting the response looka at the dump, but its working on SOApUI

Comment: hey where are you declare your envelope ?

Comment: like that SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

Comment: hey it working or not ?

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi hey it has the envelope sorry its noy  in my question, i edited now,but it is still not working

Comment: Is there header part are required in your webservice ? if yes then add header part..

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi can u please tell me how to put the header, i mean what will be the header of my wsdl file. http://pastebin.com/MjMCHTR1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48456/discussion-between-anjali-tripathi-and-teekib)